# Adding jquery mobile swipe event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listview and what I am trying to do is add a swipe event on the links. For example, if a user swipes the first link it goes to that page. Is this possible with listview elements. I have tried div,href,a,li,ul but still no alert. It works with body. Thanks

```
<div>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
   <li class="rqstpage"><a href="./requests.php">Requests</a></li>
   <li><a href="./speakers.php" data-transition="pop">Control Panel</a></li>
   <li><a href="./schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
   <li><a href="./information.html">Information</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<script>
$("div ul li.rqstpage").bind('swipe',function(event, ui){
  $.mobile.changePage("requests.php", "slide");
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 I'm going to try creating a photo gallery with swipe gestures

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/4/

JS:

```
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1"> 
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">Back to the Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p>
            Yeah!<br />You Swiped Right to view Page 1
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Related:

- [Adding JQM swipe event to listview link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298915/adding-jqm-swipe-event-to-listview-link)

Comment: Phil is it not possible to have a <a href="#"> so that it retains it's formatting and layout. By removing the anchor tag, the formatting, text goes haywire. thanks

Comment: @bollo did you ever figure out how to send this to a new URL instead of the DIV?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using binding using `live()`?

**UPDATE**: `.live()` will be deprecated and the correct usage is `.on()`

It attaches the handler to the event for all current matching elements **as well as those that might match later on.**

```
pageCreate() {
  $(parent).on('swipe', 'li.rqstpage', function() {
     $.mobile.changePage("requests.php", "slide");
  }
}
```

Have you considred using this library for [gestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

does it work if you bind it directly on the control, like so:

```
pageCreate() {
  $("li.rqstpage").swipe() {
     $.mobile.changePage("requests.php", "slide");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to slide in the natural direction that the user swipes, then do it like this:

```
// For a left swipe: page slides from right to left
$('#listitem').on('swipeleft', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage('#page-to-left', { transition: slide});
});

// For a right swipe: page slides from left to right (add "reverse: true")
$('#listitem').on('swiperight', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage('#page-to-right', { transition: slide, reverse: true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want transition you need to specify that you want transition also such as

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page1', { transition: 'flip' });
```