# Adding JQM swipe event to listview link

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to find any examples on how to code jquery mobile swipe event. Although I understand the principal of using swipe and tap etc, I am struggling to get one to work. If someone could show me a small example of using swipe with a href or listview href I would be grateful. Thanks

```
<p>
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
  <li id="listitem"><a href="#" data-transition="flip">Requests</a><p>Box requests include, Retrieval, Return, New Intake</p></li>
  <li><a href="./speakers.php" data-transition="pop">Control Panel</a><p>Add Departments, Change Password etc</p></li>
  <li><a href="./information.html">Information</a><p>System messages, announcements are shown here</p></li>
 </ul>
</p>

<script>

pageCreate() {
  $("#listitem").swiperight() {
     $.mobile.changePage("requests.php");
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/4/

JS:

```
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1"> 
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">Back to the Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p>
            Yeah!<br />You Swiped Right to view Page 1
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Related:

- [Adding jquery mobile swipe event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293220/adding-jquery-mobile-swipe-event)

Comment: is it possible to link to a URL instead of a new DIV? If so, how?  Thanks!

Comment: @SnowboardBruin Have you tried using the physical page name eg 'somepage.html' ?

Answer (score 0):

should be pretty easy according to [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

```
<li id="listitem"></li>

pageCreate() {
  $("#listitem").swiperight() {
     $.mobile.changePage("url");
  }
}
```

Comment: Tsar in the doc link you posted, there is no exampl

Comment: Tsar not working. no swipe effect or movement. Please see code added to my question. is that correct mark-up. Thanks

Comment: check this: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2011/3/14/Using-swipe-gestures-for-navigation-in-jQuery-Mobile