# jquerymobile: page animations

Tags: animation, jquery-mobile

I have 2 pages embedded on my single HTML file. so what it does is that initially it shows PAGE1, then if i swipe from right to left OR left to right PAGE2 should show. my problem is how can I change the page animation based on my swipe? like when I swipe form right to left the animation should be the page scrolling from right to left and vice versa?

i am aware of the page swipe events but i dont know how to programatically change its animation

thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated Answer:

If you're looking for page transitions I would suggest reading:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

Example:

Adding this attribute will slide from right to left

```
data-transition="slide"
```

Adding these attributes will slide from left to right

```
data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse"
```

Original Answer below:

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/4/

JS:

```
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1"> 
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">Back to the Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p>
            Yeah!<br />You Swiped Right to view Page 1
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Related:

- [Adding JQM swipe event to listview link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298915/adding-jqm-swipe-event-to-listview-link)
- [Adding jquery mobile swipe event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293220/adding-jquery-mobile-swipe-event)

Comment: hi! thanks again phil! actually i can do the swipe left and swipe right events.... but my actual problem is the page animation... its like when i swipe from right to left i want the transition be from right to left and vice versa.... it actually works fine when i have lots of page interconnected. but I just want 2 alternating page like (PAGE1 and PAGE2)... an example scenario is when im in PAGE2 then I swipe to right, i want the transition be from right to left and when I swipe to left, the transition will be left to right.

Comment: $.mobile.changePage( $("#pageid"), { transition: "slide", reverse: false or true} ); <- this solves my problem. thanks phil

Answer (score -1):

Do you have data-rel="back" in your li or button?

Comment: hi, i dont have any buttons or li. i want the whole page swipeable so whatever part of the page i swipe i can do so... but my problem is not the swipe event but the actual page animations

Comment: Just as an FYI, JQM is downgrading transitions on Android devices. It looks like everything below Android 4.0 OS will automatically use fade instead, starting with the next JQueryMobile update. This was due to poor animations on Andorid devices.

Comment: i see. thanks for that information. ill keep it in mind. as of now ill only support mobile safari