# How to create with jquery mobile a swipeable div over a list?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, swipe

First of all, I use jquery-1.7.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js.

I have a jquery mobile list like this

```
 <ul id="myList" data-role="listview">
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      ...
 </ul>
```

As I want to build a pagination for this list via swiperight and swipeleft over all list items I am wondering how to implement this?

I used...

```
$("#ulList").swiperight(function () {
    // pagination logic
});
```

but this is not working, except I swipe exactly between the list items :)

Is there any possibility to overlay a div or something, so that I can click my list items AND have a swipe right and left area over all list items???

thanks for your help!

regards from germany

Comment: have you seen the answers to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298915/adding-jqm-swipe-event-to-listview-link)?

Comment: oh thanks, i will try it out. sry, didn't see this post when searching for an answer...

Comment: sorry, that post couldn't help my, because i got it working with **<li>bar</li>**, but not with **<li><a href="#">foo</a></li>**

Comment: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/2188/

Comment: great! so if you answered your question yourself, you can add it as answer below and accept your answer to close it.

Comment: oh sry, my question isn't answerered, because it still doesn't work yet as i wanted it. i need this anchor in the list item, but i just get it work without the anchor :(

Comment: no one any idea how to handle this problem???????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq **What if I don’t get a good answer?** First, make sure you’ve asked a good question. To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. **Edit your question** to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

Comment: @Taifun To be honest I don't think its a good question. It's not exactly clear what is being asked &/or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @PhillHealey digging out old questions? Btw: I was not the one who asked...

Comment: @Taifun No, looking for answers to an issue of my own. However, you are correct about not being the OP. Sorry.