# HTML iOS7 Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using this iOS7 design for my web app: http://c2prods.com/2013/cloning-the-ui-of-ios-7-with-html-css-and-javascript/
(source code: https://github.com/fredfortier/angular-ios7 )
And I wanted to add the function that real iOS7 apps have - the function that when you swipe from the left of the screen to the right side, it goes to previeus page.
How can I do that?

Comment: you can do this using jQuery...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293220/adding-jquery-mobile-swipe-event

Comment: @rider Hey, the swiperight method works on every position in the screen (even if im on center sliding 50 pixels right.. is there a way to do it like iOS7 - that the slide only happens when the swipe was at the left side of the screen?